# How to properly attach image into background with the bootstrap template that has been attached

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, background-image

With this help desk application I've created, I'm trying to use an `MacbookBackbround.jpg` as the background image of the website in order to get rid of the whitespace. I've tried the following code to no avail:

```
<div>
    <style>
        .main-content {
            background-image: 
            url('../../../../wwwroot/images/MacbookBackground.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

I also tried modifying the theme.css code and tried modifying .container to no avail as well.

https://github.com/zhadjah9559/HelpDeskTicket/tree/3.LoginAndDB

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a little unclear what exactly you are having trouble with, I can tell you that to have a background image you need to do a little bit more than just adding in the background-image property. In your CSS you add a background-image property to your HTML element with a link to your image file. If you want your image to fill up the entire browser window and be centered you will have to add the  height, background-position, background-repeat, and  background-size properties.

CSS

```
   html {
        background-image: url("some_img.jpg");
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```